# how does magento store relationship between store and root category in database

Tags: mysql, magento

FYI this is Magento 1.4 which might possibly change things but I'm fairly certain the answer is no.

We have thousands of stores in our Magento site, each representing a school.  Each store is supposed to have a Root Category assigned.

My question is simple, where in the db tables is this relationship stored?  I would like to search for stores by root category, and programmatically (or better yet by db query also) update this information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stored in `core_store_group.root_category_id`.

This will return a collection of stores which have a root category ID of 1.

```
$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('root_category_id', array('eq' => 1));
```